# "Related" not showing up when using the website searchbox

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, search, related-questions

When I get to your website from a Blekko search, I'm getting the 'Related' questions listed on the right.  These are very helpful and often land me to what I am looking for.

But when I do a search from the searchbox on the upper right, I don't see Related questions.

I think they should be displayed anytime one is viewing a question.

Answer (score 2):

The list of Related will show when you're viewing a single question.

When you're searching, the whole page of results are all the questions that are either relevant or related to what you're looking for.

You can't have the sidebar show related questions when you're looking at an index of multiple questions and the content of the main area are the related questions you're looking for.